# How to add anchor tag in Magento 2 Email templates?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, customer-account

I am using the below line to add Anchor tag in Email template of magento 2. But it's printing as a text.

```
<span>{{trans '<a href="www.powermax.com">www.powermax.com</a>'}}</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can only use text for translation like did

**vendor/magento/module_email/view/frontend/email/footer.html**

```
<p class="closing">{{trans "Thank you, %store_name" store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}!</p>
```

so in your case

```
 <span><a href="{{trans 'www.powermax.com'}}">{{trans 'www.powermax.com'}}</a></span>
```

because between these '**content**' consider as a **text**.